# Two Op-Amp Instrumentation Amplifier - Gain derivation

Tags: circuit-analysis, instrumentation-amplifier, superposition

I came across the following appnote([slyt647](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slyt647/slyt647.pdf)) which analyses the two op-amp instrumentation amplifier topology.

The gain was found by finding individual gains for each op-amp and adding them in accordance to superposition.
I have some hard time understading how \$G_{A1V-IN} \$ (eq 8) was calculated.
[image: Circuit Diagram]

As far as I see it for \$G_{A1V-IN} \$ we have the following equivalent circuit:

[image: schematic]

And thus it seems to me that: $$G_{A1V-IN} = -\frac{R_R}{R_G} -\frac{R_R}{R_f}\cdot \left(1+\frac{R_R}{R_f || R_G} \right) $$

Did I go wrong somewhere ?

Answer (score 1):

You're right, they ignored Rg in A2 gain. I tried to sum the currents in A1- node, I made the same mistake and I've got the same result.

Comment: Oops... Now i've fixed it.
This doesn't really answer the question though. Why does the gain term in the appnote neglect this part ?